How to use `tikzfeynmanset` to fill-in a blob in the `feynman` environment
Quite straightforward. I want the blobs in my Feynman diagrams to be filled in with gray. Hence, I tried
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}
\tikzfeynmanset{
      blob/.append style={
        fill=gray
      },
    }
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{feynman}
        \node[blob] (c) at (0,0);
        \vertex (a1) at (180:2);
        \vertex (a2) at (135:2);
        \vertex (a3) at (225:2);
        \vertex (b1) at (30:2);
        \vertex (b2) at (330:2);
        \diagram*{
            (a1) -- [fermion] (c),
            (a2) -- [fermion] (c),
            (a3) -- [fermion] (c),
            (c) -- [fermion] (b1),
            (c) -- [fermion] (b2),
        };
    \end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

This does not work. I get the message

Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/fill', to which you passed 'gray', and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

Ironically, if I don't use the feynman environment, but use \feynmandiagram instead, everything works fine. MWE:
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}
\tikzfeynmanset{
      blob/.append style={
        fill=gray
      },
    }
\begin{document}
\feynmandiagram[vertical'=i1 to i2, inline=(c.base)]{
    i1 -- [fermion] c [blob] -- [fermion] i2, 
    f1 -- [boson] c -- [boson] f2,
        i1 -- [draw=none] i2,
        i1 -- [draw=none] f1,
        f1 -- [draw=none] f2,
        i2 -- [draw=none] f2,
    };
\end{document}

How can I get a filled gray blob?

Props to you for answering your own question! As for why your two code snippets behave differently, when you call c[blob], PGF executes the key /tikz/fill=gray. In contrast, when you call \node[blob], PGF executes the key fill=gray on the root directory (not on /tikz/)

If you specify which path to use by adding \tikzfeynmanset{blob/.append style={/tikz/.cd, fill = gray}} to your preamble, then both of your code examples will work as intended. However, the every blob method in your own answer is probably the better option, since that's what the official documentation recommends.

I don't know why this works and why the attempts in the question did not, but I'll record a workaround here for future reference. Following this post, I tried
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}
\tikzfeynmanset{
      every blob={/tikz/fill=gray!30}
    }
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{feynman}
        \node[blob] (c) at (0,0);
        \vertex (a1) at (180:2);
        \vertex (a2) at (135:2);
        \vertex (a3) at (225:2);
        \vertex (b1) at (30:2);
        \vertex (b2) at (330:2);
        \diagram*{
            (a1) -- [fermion] (c),
            (a2) -- [fermion] (c),
            (a3) -- [fermion] (c),
            (c) -- [fermion] (b1),
            (c) -- [fermion] (b2),
        };
    \end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

For some reason, this works.
